# Changing variables of imported module doesnt seem to work. [Python]

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to make a separate dictionary in a python file, so I could import it and do stuff such as search key, add word, remove word. The file is dictionary.py . It contains:

```
#-*-coding:utf8-*-
dict={}
```

So when I import it in my main python file, add a word and print it, it works fine, but the dictionary.py file doesn't gets affected. I want the "dict"  variable in dictionary.py file to change too. Here's my code for the main file:

```
import os
import sys
import dictionary as tdict
print ":::::::::::::::::::"
print "Add word"
print ":::::::::::::::::::"
name=raw_input("Word: ")
print
mean=raw_input ("Meaning: ")
tdict.dict[name]=mean
print "::::Word added::::"
print
print "::::::::::::::::::::::"
print "Dictionary:"
print
for x in tdict.dict:
    print "",x,":",tdict.dict[x]`
```

Any help? thx

Comment: Do you mean you want the actual contents of `dictionary.py` to change when you add an item to `dict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not writing to the file at any point. The correct way to store a python object such as a dictionary is to use `pickle`:

```
import pickle


myDictionary = {}
dictionaryFile = open('dictionary', 'wb')
pickle.dump(mydictionary, dictionaryFile)
dictionaryFile.close()
```

This will create a pickle file called `dictionary` that contains `myDictionary`

To read the dictionary:

```
import pickle


dictionaryFile = open('dictionary', 'rb')
myDictionary = pickle.load(dictionaryFile)
dictionaryFile.close()
```

Then you can make whatever changes you want to the dictionary then save it to the file again:

```
import pickle


dictionaryFile = open('dictionary', 'rb')
myDictionary = pickle.load(dictionaryFile)
dictionaryFile.close()

myDictionary['key1'] = 'value1'

dictionaryFile = open('dictionary', 'wb')
pickle.dump(mydictionary, dictionaryFile)
dictionaryFile.close()
```